# JQuery click event inside for

Tags: jquery

I really don´t know what is happening to me..

The code is like:

```
for (var j=0; j<tours.length; j++){
    var name = tours[j].name;

    var $tourLI = $('<li id="'+name+'"></li>');
    var $tourButton = $('<div class="button-inside"><span>'+name+'</span><span></span></div>');

    $tourButton.click(function() {
        alert(name);
    }
}
```

I´m trying to bind the click event for each button which displays the tours name, but is always displaying the last tour name whichever the button I'm clicking.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: That is because the loop is complete when you click the button. Do you want to append new buttons to the document?

Comment: Yes I want that.. I will try the examples below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the click handler in a closure to 'close-over' the value of the variable `name` before the for-loop moves on.

This is because the handler isn't actually executed until you click on it, so otherwise it will simply use the current value of `name` at that time (whatever the last value in the loop was).

```
for (var j=0; j<tours.length; j++){
    var name = tours[j].name;

    var $tourLI = $('<li id="'+name+'"></li>');
    var $tourButton = $('<div class="button-inside"><span>'+name+'</span><span></span></div>');

    (function(n) {
        $tourButton.click(function() {
            alert(n);
        });
    })(name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the click is triggered `j` will have value `tours.length`. You can lock the loop value, as well as the rest of the variables through closures.

```
for (var j=0; j<tours.length; j++){
  (function(){ 
    var currentJValue = j;
    var name = tours[currentJValue].name;

    var $tourLI = $('<li id="'+name+'"></li>');
    var $tourButton = $('<div class="button-inside"><span>'+name+'</span><span></span></div>');

    $tourButton.click(function() {
        alert(name);
    }
  })();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to call click event inside loop..append the dynamically created button and  call it outside the loop and use on delegate event

try this

```
 $(document).on('click','div.button-inside',function() {
    alert($(this).text());
}
```

you can go through the [link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) if you want to read more about on delegate events...

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('.div.button-inside ').on('click',function() {
    alert($(this).text());
}
```